# Separation of statements in TOAD

Tags: oracle, toad, statements

I am a long time SQL Server users and am VERY new to Oracle.

In SQL Server, I can do the following

DROP TABLE Blah;
CREATE TABLE Blah(yada int);

When I run a similar statement in Oracle, the DROP always runs fine but the Create dosn't get touched unless I highlight that line specifically.

I tried putting / between the lines and that didn't help.

Can anyone tell this newb what he is doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TOAD you can run the current line in the editor as a single statment, or run the entire contents of the editory as a script. If your current line has more than one statment, on the the first gets executed if you are executing statement

shift-F9 runs the current statement 
f5 runs the entire contents.

Note that if the current statement is a pl/sql block - then the entire blockl will get executed with the execute statement, so if you put a begin..end around your two statements then they could be run as a unit without running the rest of whatever is on the editor. Note also that the execute statement is also intolerant of blank lines. IT will run a multi-line statment, but not if there are any blank lines in it.

Comment: Thanks Michael...by current statement do you mean whatever is highlighted?

Comment: If you highlight it, you will only run what is highlighted. If nothing is highlighted then TOAD will just run the line that the cursor happens to be on as it will be deemed the current statement.

Comment: Thanks! Pretty similar to SQL Server and SSMS. Just takes some getting used to.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a new line. And use execute as a script feature of TOAD.

F5 is the shortcut for doing that.

Comment: Thanks...I feel like a complete moron!